# Closing a pdf file via a batch script (.bat)

Tags: windows, batch-file, pdf

I use a windows batch file `.bat` for running latex command to create a pdf. To open the final pdf file, I wrote

```
pdflatex %2
START "" %2.pdf
```

Where %2 is the filename I passed it as argument. Problem is, whenever, I run the script, I have to manually close the pdf file and run the script. I want to add a command to first close the opened pdf and then run latex command and then open it

```
<CLOSE THE PDF FILE>
pdflatex %2
START "" %2.pdf
```

I didn't find a CLOSE command in the list of available commands, [Information on batch files](http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm)

Comment: I think that "" is not needed

Comment: "" is needed if %2 contains quotes; `start` considers the first set of double quotes it finds to be a title and then everything after that is the command.

Comment: @mahmood: did you find a solution for this question

Comment: @Saravanan: I think the solution in this thread is fine, but problem is that acrobat locks the PDF file while is it opened. In order to not hitting this issue, the PDF viewer has to be changed. You can use SumatraPDF which is a light weight and neat viewer. Therefore, when the tex command updates the PDF file, SumatraPDF will update it automatically without any further work. Try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend [SS64](http://ss64.com/nt/) for a list of batch commands. The command you're looking for is `taskkill`. I don't know pdflatex appears in the task manager, but the code is going to be something along the lines of

```
taskkill /IM acrord32.exe
```

Replace acrord32.exe with whatever it appears as in the task manager. You may also need to add the `/F` flag before the `/IM` to force close the program.

Comment: No I don't want to kill the process. I want the same function as close button (X).

Comment: I don't understand. How does clicking the close button not kill the program?

Comment: Yes that will close/kill the file (AcroRd32.exe). I think `taskkill` operates as (kill process) in windows task manager. Am I right?

Comment: No, he's starting the registered PDF-viewer on the local system. So  it's fx Adobe Reader or similar that will need to be closed.

Comment: So replace pdflatex.exe with acrord32.exe. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: No you are right. Something is not clear for me. Is there any difference among 1)clicking on X button, 2) kill process in task manager and 3)taskkill command? Surely there is a difference!

Comment: Those all do the same thing unless you've got one of those annoying programs that thinks the red X just means minimize.

Comment: But I don't think. Normally closing a program let the program to properly end its tasks and free the memory. Killing the program means freeing the memory from OS side. Assume you have an open unsaved file. Closing the program warns you but killing the program won't warn you

Comment: OK I modified the PDF and `taskkill /IM AcroRd32.exe` warns me about saving changes. So that command normally close the program

Comment: `taskkill /IM AcroRd32.exe` closes all open files/windows, while clicking X would close only one.

Comment: I've been searching for this command for years! Thank you!